# In urdf tutorial(r2d2), rivz showed `global status:Frame [map] does not exist

Tags: ros2, rviz, urdf

Both launch files worked fine, but in rviz it showed `global status:Frame [map] does not exist`.

Results of searching the rviz environment storage file

```
  Enabled: true
  Global Options:
    Background Color: 48; 48; 48
    Fixed Frame: odom
    Frame Rate: 30
  Name: root
```

It is set to , but I don't know why the initial setting is set to map.
thank you